Diophantine approximation for polynomials in a single variable
Let $a_0, a_1, \cdots, a_n$ be non-zero algebraic numbers. Consider the polynomial
$$\displaystyle f(x) = a_n x^n + \cdots + a_1 x + a_0.$$
For a real number $\alpha$, put $\lVert \alpha \rVert$ for the distance of $\alpha$ to the nearest integer.
Suppose that $f(k)$ is never an integer for $k \in \mathbb{Z} \setminus \{0\}$. Is there a lower bound for $\lVert f(k) \rVert$ as $k$ runs over the non-zero integers, as a function of $f$ and $k$?
In the case when $n = 1$ and $a_0 \in \mathbb{Z}$, then the question can be interpreted as asking for a lower bound for $|a_1 q - p|$ as $p,q$ run over the integers. Our hypothesis asserts that $a_1$ is not rational, so we can apply Roth's theorem and say that $|a_1 q - p| \geq C(a_1, \varepsilon) q^{-1 - \varepsilon}$ for all $\varepsilon > 0$, with some constant $C(a_1,\varepsilon)$ dependent on $a_1, \varepsilon$.

If $n=1$, and $a_0$ is an integer, then $f(0)$ is an integer. The lower bound for $|a_1q-p|$ is zero, achieved when $p=q=0$.

Thanks for the observation, I edited the question to remove this triviality.

I would try the subspace theorem using the fact that the rational normal curve in projective space is not linearly degenerate.
